# cocos2d v2 scale my background

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have install cocos2d v2.0, and i am working a little on it, to see what changed against v1, i have create a simple cocos2d + box2d project, and i run it and all work fine, i have deleted the IntroLayer and the Helloworld Layer, i have tried to display a simple background layer, so i have do this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface BackgroundLayer : CCLayer

@end

#import "BackgroundLayer.h"

@implementation BackgroundLayer

-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {

    CCSprite *backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    backgroundImage.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
}

return self;
}

@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "BackgroundLayer.h"

@interface GameScene : CCScene

@end

#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {

    BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
    [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

and then in the app delegate i have changed this:

```
[director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]];
```

in this:

```
[director_ pushScene: [GameScene node]];
```

but the seem scaled of the 0.5, i have created the hd and the not hd image, for retina and not retina, what i wrong? this is the result:

http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4778/schermata072456124alle1.png

**EDIT:**
if i change the BackgroundLayer.m in this way, all work fine:

```
@implementation BackgroundLayer

/*-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {

    CCSprite *backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    backgroundImage.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
}

return self;
}*/

-(void) onEnter
{
[super onEnter];
CCSprite *backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
backgroundImage.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
[self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
}

@end
```

anyone can explain me why? i remember that in the old version of cocos2d i can add the layer in the init method...

Comment: hmmm have you checked that the -hd file has twice the width and height of the SD file? Or maybe the image simply has a transparent area in its lower right corner.

Comment: the image are perfect, so why in the edit i write above all work?...if the image was wrong also the second method i write in the edit shouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Use this style, worked in cocos2d 2.0 also.

```
@interface GameScene : CCLayer
{

}
+(CCScene *) scene;
@end

#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    GameScene *gameScenelayer = [GameScene node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: gameScenelayer];

    // return the scene 
    return scene;
}


-(id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

        CCSprite *backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        backgroundImage.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

//Call this

```
[director_ pushScene: [GameScene scene]];
```